# changing the palette in a bar plot in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I'm checking the Bokeh tutorials, and I'm not able to change the palette in a Bar plot. In particular, I'm trying to complete the last exercise in 
[this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/01%20-%20charts.ipynb) with the following code:

```
from bokeh.palettes import brewer                                                                    
from bokeh.palettes import Blues5,YlGnBu9, YlOrBr9, YlOrRd9
bar = Bar(medals,label="name",values="count",stack="medal",agg="sum",color="medal",palette=Blues5)
show(bar)
```

Whatever palette I try from the second line, the result is the same. Am I missing something? I'm using Bokeh 0.10.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've used this:

```
 color = color(columns = 'Week of', palette = palettes.Set1_9)
```

Here I am saying what palette to use while saying what column to color by

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I find works, it will color each bar of the chart according to the 'Cost' of the object.

```
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256

mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Viridis256, low=0, high=150)
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, location=(0,0))

plot = df.plot_bokeh.bar(
    x='Date',
    y='Cost',
    title='Expenses'
    color= {'field': 'Cost', 'transform': mapper})

show(plot)
```

You can see the result here:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oVLr.png